# Asus laptop, no RAID option available

Tags: bios, raid-0

I currently have 2 SSD's in my Asus N551VW (skylake I7-6700HQ, chipset supports RAID 0) and I'm trying to configure them as RAID 0.

There is a "SATA Mode" option available in the BIOS but the only option I can pick is AHCI, no IDE/RAID option.

These two SSD's are not formatted and I'm not sure if that's the problem or not. I just wanted to see if I could get the RAID option to show before going ahead and formatting my two drives.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: RAID0 although will give you the best performance is the worst for disaster recovery... why you'd want to use RAID0 without some other RAID configuration is beyond any IT professional... a single disk failure of RAID0 will leave the entire array destroyed with almost zero recovery.

Comment: I don't really care about recovery, these two drives are both 120gb and I want to combine them so I could fit my OS'es and Games on there without running out of space. My documents/important files will be stored safely on a seperate 1TB hard drive so if the RAID files nothing important is lost.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?